# how to add zero if two columns are not in length?

Tags: awk

I have two columns but one column has 20 data while the second column has 16 data. So I want to make both columns equal in length. So how to add zeros?
I have a file like:

```
1 2  
3 4   
4 5  
7    
8   
8
```

So the first column has  6 elements while the second column has 3 elements. So I want to make both the column equal by adding zero to the second column.
so output file should be like:

```
1 2        
3 4  
4 5   
7 0  
8 0    
8 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NF < 2 {$2 = 0}; 1' < file
```

Would set the second field to `0` if the number of fields (`NF`) is less than 2 in a given record.

Note that for lines with no field (blank lines), that would give `" 0"`. Instead, you could do:

```
awk 'NF < 1 {$1 = 0}; NF < 2 {$2 = 0}; 1' < file
```

For those lines to become `"0 0"` instead or:

```
awk 'NF && NF < 2 {$2 = 0}; 1' < file
```

to leave those blank lines alone.

Comment: or `awk '{ $2+=0 }1' <file`; if blank lines `awk 'NF{ $2+=0 }1' <file`

Comment: @αғsнιη, yes, though that would change 010 or 10.0 (or possibly 10,0) or 1e1 to 10 for instance and N/A to 0. IOW, that forces the string -> number -> string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk -v OFS=" " '{if ($2=="") print $0,0; else print $0}' file
1 2  
3 4   
4 5  
7 0
8 0
8 0
```

Comment: Note that SPC (`" "`) is already the default value of `OFS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that purpose:

```
awk '{if (NF == 2) print $1 " " $2; else if (NF == 1) print $1 " 0";}' input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

This will read the file line-wise, and for all those lines which have two "fields" (i.e. space-separated bunches of text), print those two, but for all lines which have only one field, print that one and a "0" with separating space in between.

Note that no text adjustment is performed here, and I assumed that the file only contains lines with one or two numbers, so no checks are performed here (although it would be easy to include them). Any lines which do not have either one or two fields will be ignored in the output.